# olddomain.com(path and file(s).pdf) to newdomain.com (path and file(s).pdf)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

olddomain.com/path/file(s).pdf contains several hundred files that are pdfs with unique names.

We have a newdomain.com and the path is the same and the files are the same except when a user types in olddomain.com/path/file.pdf we want them to automatically be sent to newdomain.com/path/file.pdf

Again, the file names and the paths are identical, just want a way to redirect the domain names portion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.pdf -f
RewriteRule ^path/(.*) http://www.newdomain.com/path/$1.pdf [R]
```